# Google Spreadsheet - importXML with JS

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I try import mail address, witch is a protected with JS.
Could you see in example link.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c257kLubJxfKQGOfN5C_PKdQxaBT5lt-tVC6k3hctJI/edit?usp=sharing

Is there a way to do this?
Thank you.

Comment: Which part of website are you trying to retrieve? Could you attach screenshot?

Comment: From this webpage. https://www.azet.sk/firma/342067/eurocross-assistance-czech-republic-s-r-o/ My idea: https://imgur.com/a/EICakTu

Comment: It probably won't be possible, will it?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I tried multiple ways including Apps Script but wasn't successful on retrieving the data. I believe web scraping javascript website can be done using another programming language such as python.